# best way to store url in mysql for a read&write-intensive application

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

What is the best way to store url in mysql effectively for a read&write-intensive application?

I will be storing over 500,000 web addresses (all starting with either http:// or https://. no other protocols) and saving the whole url (http://example.com/path/?variable=a) into one column seems to be largely redundant because the same domain name and path will be saved to mysql multiple times.

So, initially, I thought of breaking them down (i.e. domain, path, and variables, etc) to get rid of redundancy. But I saw some posts saying that it's not recommended. Any idea on this?

Also, the application often has to retrieve urls without primary keys, meaning it has to search text to retrieve url. URL can be indexed, but I'm wondering how much performance difference there would be between storing the whole url and broken-down-url if they are all indexed under innodb(no full text indexing).

Broken-down-url will have to go through extra steps of combining them. Also, it would mean that I have to retrieve data 4 times from different tables(protocol, domain, path, variable), but it also makes the stored data in each row shorter and there would be less rows in each table. Would this possibly speed up the process?

Answer (score 8):

I have dealt with this extensively, and my general philosophy is to use the frequency of use method. It's cumbersome, but it lets you run some great analytics on the data:

```
CREATE TABLE URL (
   ID            integer unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   DomainPath    integer unsigned NOT NULL,
   QueryString   text
) Engine=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE DomainPath (   
   ID            integer unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Domain        integer unsigned NOT NULL,
   Path          text,
   UNIQUE (Domain,Path)
) Engine=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE Domain (   
   ID            integer unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Protocol      tinyint NOT NULL,
   Domain        varchar(64)
   Port          smallint NULL,
   UNIQUE (Protocol,Domain,Port)
) Engine=MyISAM;
```

As a general rule, you'll have similar Paths on a single Domain, but different QueryStrings for each path.

I originally designed this to have all parts indexed in a single table (Protocol, Domain, Path, Query String) but think the above is less space-intensive and lends better to getting better data out of it.

`text` tends to be slow, so you can change "Path" to a varchar after some use. Most servers die after about 1K for a URL, but I've seen some large ones and would err on the side of not losing data.

Your retrieval query is cumbersome, but if you abstract it away in your code, no issue:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    IF(D.Protocol=0,'http://','https://'),
    D.Domain,
    IF(D.Port IS NULL,'',CONCAT(':',D.Port)), 
    '/', DP.Path, 
    IF(U.QueryString IS NULL,'',CONCAT('?',U.QueryString))
)
FROM URL U
INNER JOIN DomainPath DP ON U.DomainPath=DP.ID
INNER JOIN Domain D on DP.Domain=D.ID
WHERE U.ID=$DesiredID;
```

Store a port number if it's non standard (non-80 for http, non-443 for https), otherwise store it as NULL to signify it shouldn't be included. (You can add the logic to the MySQL but it gets much uglier.)

I would always (or never) strip the "/" from the Path as well as the "?" from the QueryString for space savings. Only loss would being able to distinguish between

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/?
```

Which, if important, then I would change your tack to never strip it and just include it. Technically,

```
http://www.example.com 
http://www.example.com/
```

Are the same, so stripping the Path slash is OK always.

So, to parse:

```
http://www.example.com/my/path/to/my/file.php?id=412&crsource=google+adwords
```

We would use something like `parse_url` in PHP to produce:

```
array(
    [scheme] => 'http',
    [host] => 'www.example.com',
    [path] => '/my/path/to/my/file.php',
    [query] => 'id=412&crsource=google+adwords',
)
```

You would then check/insert (with appropriate locks, not shown):

```
SELECT D.ID FROM Domain D 
WHERE 
    D.Protocol=0 
    AND D.Domain='www.example.com' 
    AND D.Port IS NULL
```

(if doesn't exist)

```
INSERT INTO Domain ( 
    Protocol, Domain, Port 
) VALUES ( 
    0, 'www.example.com', NULL 
);
```

We then have our `$DomainID` going forward...

Then insert into DomainPath:

```
SELECT DP.ID FORM DomainPath DP WHERE 
DP.Domain=$DomainID AND Path='/my/path/to/my/file.php';
```

(if it doesn't exist, insert it similarly)

We then have our `$DomainPathID` going forward...

```
SELECT U.ID FROM URL 
WHERE 
    DomainPath=$DomainPathID 
    AND QueryString='id=412&crsource=google+adwords'
```

and insert if necessary.

Now, let me note *importantly*, that the above scheme will be slow for high-performance sites. You should modify everything to use a hash of some sort to speed up `SELECT`s. In short, the technique is like:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
     ID integer unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     Hash varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
     Content text
) Type=MyISAM;

SELECT ID FROM Foo WHERE Hash=UNHEX(MD5('id=412&crsource=google+adwords'));
```

I deliberately eliminated it from the above to keep it simple, but comparing a TEXT to another TEXT for selects is slow, and breaks for really long query strings. Don't use a fixed-length index either because that will also break. For arbitrary length strings where accuracy matters, a hash failure rate is acceptable.

Finally, if you can, do the MD5 hash client side to save sending large blobs to the server to do the MD5 operation. Most modern languages supports MD5 built-in:

```
SELECT ID FROM Foo WHERE Hash=UNHEX('82fd4bcf8b686cffe81e937c43b5bfeb');
```

But I digress.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have some questions: is "querystring" a column for variables of a url? also, how do you distinguish id's between urls with no variables, path, etc, when you are retrieving by id? for example, if you are given an id, how can you tell which table to look up unless you have a separate table that contains all the ids.

Comment: You only store IDs to the URL table, it stores references to the subtables. If you want to just reference a domain name (elsewhere, for some other reason), store IDs to the Domain table elsewhere. I'll update the example with an example.

Comment: And, you should probably use a "Hash" of some sort (described at the end) to convert from URL -> ID. ID -> URL is shown in the example above (with the CONCAT). Also, run all URLs through "url_normalize($url)" (which you'll have to write) which makes the scheme and host lowercase, and converts `http://foo:80/` to `http://foo/`

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do with the data. if you're doing statistics with the URLs e.g. to see what domains are the most popular, then it would be feasible to break it down through that. But if you are just storing them and accessing the url in it's entirety, there's no reason to split them up.

I've seen some people hashing long strings (e.g. md5) and searching against that, there might be a performance enhancement for URLs, but I'm not certain by how much (it's better for lots of text).

Whatever you do - don't forget to always use ints as primary keys as much as possible as those are the quickest lookups.

If you really want to split your URLs, you may want to consider keeping separate tables in order to not lock your table (in innoDB it doesn't matter as the table doesn't get locked up) but with seperate tables, you can just use foreign/primary_keys/ints to reference the rows you need.

A good read is [friendfeed's blog entry](http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql) - that might give you some ideas as well:

Comment: why is there no reason to split them up if i can avoid redundancy by splitting them up? just wondering

Comment: If the sole purpose of storing your URLs is to read it from the row in it's entirety, then you already have the data broken down the way you want it. However, if you want to do something else with it, say - statistical analysis on which domains are the most popular, it would be more feasible to break it up.